# Compare two lists and return a list of binary values for matches of the same numbers by the same indices

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to determine matches between the elements of my two lists. For example, if I have the following two lists:

```
x = [3, 5, 6, 7]
y = [3, 5, 7, 9]
```

how do I get the following list with 1's where values match and 0's where values do not match?

```
expected_output = [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This one:

```
x = [3,5,6,7]
y = [5, 7, 9]
compare_order = [1 if i==j else 0 for i, j in zip(x,y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1, l2 = [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 3]
len(l1) == len(l2) and all(i == j for i, j in zip(l1, l2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **filter** function:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
result = list(filter(lambda i: list1[i]==list2[i], range(0, min(len(list1), len(list2)))))
print(len(result))
```

*Assuming your function is returning 2 in my example since number 1 and 4 are in the same positions in the two lists here is on possibility.*

Note that the filter function take as input the range of values between 0 and the minimum length between our two lists. Then it filter out all the indexes that are not pointing at the same value in both lists.

So result is basically containing all the indexes that in both lists contain the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5]
list2 = [1,1,7,4,8,5,6]
```

we can use a normal nested for loop as below:

```
for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    for i1, v1 in enumerate(list2):
        if (i==i1) & (v==v1):
            print(i,v)
```

which prints the index and value which matches

**Output**

```
0 1
3 4
5 5
```

The same can be converted into a nested list comprehension

```
In [21]:[(i,v) for i1, v1 in enumerate(list2) for i, v in enumerate(list1) if (i==i1) & (v==v1)]
Out[21]:
[(0, 1), (3, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Returns a list of (index, value) that matches

Answer (score -1):

I think that simply comparing the two lists with operator == should do the job

```
>>> a = [0,3,4,5]
>>> b = [0,3,5,4]
>>> a == b
False
>>> c = [0,3,4,5]
>>> a == c
True
```

Or you can try this maybe:

```
>>> for index, item in enumerate(a):
...     if item == b[index]:
...             print "same"
...     else:
...             print "different"
```